# Are questions about tracking on-topic for this site?

Tags: discussion, scope

The question that piqued my interest isn't directly related to tracking, because the animal in question has been extinct for a few dozen million years: [What species of dinosaur made these 3 toed 6 inch long tracks?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/16972/3076)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is and we already have a few questions on the subject,

- [Are these tracks in the mud tortoise/turtle tracks?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/13067/are-these-tracks-in-the-mud-tortoise-turtle-tracks)
- [What animal is making odd footprints and squeaking sounds under my guest house?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/10697/what-animal-is-making-odd-footprints-and-squeaking-sounds-under-my-guest-house)
- [After I've shot large game, and it escapes, how can I track it?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/528/after-ive-shot-large-game-and-it-escapes-how-can-i-track-it)
- [Is it possible to differentiate between a dog print and wolf print?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/11632/is-it-possible-to-differentiate-between-a-dog-print-and-wolf-print/11633#11633)
- [Did I see a wolf's pawprint?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/11613/did-i-see-a-wolfs-pawprint)

The current close votes on the dino track one aren't because its off topic but rather because it might be [hard to answer](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1044/why-was-my-question-about-the-arrowhead-closed-as-opinion-based). However, I highly doubt that it will be closed.

Comment: The close votes on the dino track question are aging off, so it seems likely it will stay open.  Have you considered posting the dino questions at Biology?  They have a [dinosaurs tag](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dinosaurs) or alternately trying to get one of the dino experts there to visit here?

Comment: @JamesJenkins There is nothing exactly similar on Biology.

Answer (score 2):

To address Dinosaur tracks directly.

I was an early opponent of questions about Dinosaur tracks.  I voted to close several posts.  The close votes either aged off, or the posts were re-opened by vote.

In the process I did a bit of research and have changed my position on the subject.

I believe they are clearly inscope for 3 reason:

1. Community consensus to close these questions did not develop.
2. There are US state parks with a primary focus on Dinosuar tracks like [Dinosaur Valley State Park; Mapping Dinosaur Tracks](https://tpwd.texas.gov/state-parks/dinosaur-valley/dino-tracks)
3. We have a number of [open questions with good answers about the subject](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fossil-identification+dinosaurs)