# Can we re-tag all dinosaur questions?

Tags: discussion, tagging

This comes out [off a topic in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44190828#44190828). I don't see how this has a place. Being as we couldn't agree I'm opening it out to the wider community to vote on.

The [dinosaur](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dinosaur) tag is just misleading and it's wiki:

> Questions about dinosaurs

Is just confusing. We don't want questions about dinosaurs. That makes no sense. Do we want people asking "What a T.Rex ate"? What do dinosaurs have to do with "The Outdoors"?

So the person who created the [dinosaur](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dinosaur) tag has re-tagged everything to [dinosaurs](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dinosaurs).....

Same argument applies...

Comment: The downvoter is welcome to add a conflicting answer as to why we should keep the tag [tag:dinosaur]?

Comment: Does the photography tag mean that photography is on topic here instead of the stack dedicated to it?

Comment: We should also consider having "dinosaur" and "dinosaurs" be synonyms for whatever tag folksonomy we decide on

Answer (score 4):

Yes re-tag all [dinosaur](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dinosaur) questions as [fossil](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fossil). All the dinosaur questions are asking about fossil records and fossil is much more clearly on topic for this site.

Answer (score 3):

No, instead change [dinosaur](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dinosaur) to something more general, such as "paleontology", and add [fossil](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fossil) tags to the questions mentioned.

Furthermore, other SE sites employ a similar tactic, using a tag "paleontology" as a catch-all for these kinds of questions:

https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paleontology

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paleontology

https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/palaeontology

Comment: Its not a problem to have both narrow and broad tags on a question, we have both [tag:robins] and [tag:birds] on the same questions

Comment: Biology ues both Dinosaur, Fossil and Paleontology tags, while Earth Science uses just Paleontology and Fossil. TGO scope/focus is going to be closer to Earth Science then Biology on these type of questions. I like your proposal and reasoning. I also note you are the author of the best answers to questions being discussed. Your suggestion has my vote.

Answer (score 2):

No there are many types of fossils.

The suggestion to merge/re-tag [dinosaur](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dinosaur) into [fossil](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fossil) is like suggesting merge/re-tag [animals](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animals) and [trees](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trees) into [tag:living_things], then of course we would need a second tag... [tag:Dead_things] and we could delete all the other tags.

Comment: I don't concur that merging [tag:dinosaur] and [tag:fossil] is akin to merging [tag:animals] and [tag:trees]. This site is about the outdoors, so discussions on paleontology should be rare enough to fit under a single tag. For example, what about trilobites? We would need a new tag. And another for pteradons, and another for plesiosaurs, and...

Comment: Happy to have multiple fossil tags is required but dinosaur still make no sense to me fossil-dinosaur would be more appropriate as it doesn't imply dinosaurs are on topic.

Comment: I say happy to have multiple fossil tags in that I think it's better than dinosaur...

Comment: So maybe we need an answer here that says tag as 'dinosaur_fossils'?

Comment: @JamesJenkins We have a dogs tag, but that doesn't mean that all questions about dogs are on topic. I would say the same for dinosaurs

Comment: extinct species.

Comment: @ab2 or extinct animals?

Answer (score -3):

Let's start with why these questions are on topic

- **Dinosaur tracks are found in the outdoors.**
- Questions about [tracking](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1163/are-questions-about-tracking-on-topic-for-this-site) are on topic, here are the existing [ones](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal-tracks).
- Identification of [things in the outdoors is on topic](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal-identification+or+bird-identification+or+bug-identification+or+plant-identification+or+manmade-object-identification+or+knot-identification+or+fungi-identification+or+fossil-identification+or+identification+or+tree-identification+or+scat-identification+or+mountain-identification+or+gear-identification).
- [Fossils](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fossils) are on topic.

Regarding why it needs to stay even though some questions about dinosaurs might be off topic look at these questions,

- [Photography and camera questions](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photography+or+dslr) even though there is a dedicated SE for that.
- [Questions about pets](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dogs) again with a dedicated SE.
- [Legality questions](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legality) again with a dedicated SE.
- [Questions about biking](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biking) again with a dedicated SE.

Current naming convention for animals into which [dinosaurs](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dinosaurs) fits right in.

- [birds](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/birds)
- [deer](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deer)
- [bears](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bears)
- [turtles](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/turtles)
- [robins](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robins)

There is a convention that both the broad and the specific tags get used until a tag gets to a certain size. For example [birds](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/birds) and [bears](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bears) are both [animals](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animals) but they are big enough to stand on their own while [robins](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robins) is not. **Not being big enough to stand alone however, isn't reason to burn a tag.**

In this case, I don't care if [fossils](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fossils) is added, even though [fossil-identification](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fossil-identification) is already there.

**I firmly want  [dinosaurs](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dinosaurs) to stay.**

Comment: If dinosaurs were extant I would agree, but finding a robin in the wild is much more likely than finding a dinosaur track. As outdoorsmen, we routinely interact with birds and deer and bears and turtles and robins, but it's more rare to come across a fossil.